# How to run exe stored on machine A from machine B using VB6?

Tags: vb6

How to Access the VB EXE File in the remote machine?

I want to run exe stored on machine A from machine B using VB6

Need VB 6.0 Code Help.

Comment: It would still run in the context of machine B. provided you have permissions. you sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check out [PS Exec](http://live.sysinternals.com/psexec.exe) from Sysinternals.  It does exactly what you want and does not require any VB6 goo, such as DCOM.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the exe to run **on machine B** would be easy. Presumably you want it to run **on machine A**.

I've never tried it myself, but this sounds like a job for [DCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model). Here's a [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266717) that walks you through DCOM with VB6. You create an ActiveX exe on machine A, and then VB6 code running on machine B can call into the exe running on machine A. You haven't said what the exe actually needs to do, but presumably you can create one or more methods in a class to do it - whatever it is - and you can pass any necessary information between the machines with the method calls.